# Conversion from float_time to float

Tags: odoo

As we all know that we can use float field for time with the help of `widget="float_time"`.

Now, my question is that how this float_time value is calculated/converted into float value.

**Ex:**

I am giving value **00:10** in my form and when I look into the db it shows **0.16666667**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code in js for displaying value in float_time format:

```
case 'float_time':
        var pattern = '%02d:%02d';
        if (value < 0) {
            value = Math.abs(value);
            pattern = '-' + pattern;
        }
        var hour = Math.floor(value);
        var min = Math.round((value % 1) * 60);
        if (min == 60){
            min = 0;
            hour = hour + 1;
        }
        return _.str.sprintf(pattern, hour, min);
```

So in your case, in db it is stored as 0.16666667. So the min will be `var min = Math.round((0.16666667 % 1) * 60);` which will be 10 when rounded...

Answer (score 0):

```
def float_time_convert(float_val):
    factor = float_val < 0 and -1 or 1
    val = abs(float_val)
    return (factor * int(math.floor(val)), "{:0>2d}".format(int(round((val % 1) * 60))))
```

print "%i:%s" %(float_time_convert(3.61))